# Django Content-Type : Checking if a field is declared as Many-to-Many field

Tags: django, django-models

I checking few field names passed by the APIs from the browser and validating them before passing to Django ORM queries.

The question is for a given mode and given field name, how can I determine if the field is declared as Many-to-Many field using the Content-Type framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the field and check its [`.many_to_many`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.many_to_many) property:

```
>>> content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model="<model_name>")
>>> field = content_type.model_class()._meta.get_field("<field_name>")
>>> field.many_to_many
True
```

Comment: Thanks @ozgur. Slightly managed to come up with a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might not require content-type for this to be precise. If you already have the model or an instance handy, you would get the list of m2m fields as below

```
m2m_fields = [field.name for field in _object._meta.many_to_many]
```

If you are after just the field name a.k.a concrete fields use as below

```
fields = [field.name for field in _object._meta.concrete_fields ]
```